# Plot raster in synusoidal projection in python

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, matplotlib, cartopy

I want to plot data in a matrix, with two other matrices with coordinates, with a sinusoidal projection, in Python.

I read data and coordinates from HDF5 or NetCDF files in the form of numpy arrays. The data is already projected in a sinusoidal projection. The coordinates in the other arrays are the latitudes and longitudes of the projected data. So I have these three matrices, with data, latitudes, and longitudes:
[image: Data]
[image: lats][image: lons]

And I want an output similar to:

[image]

Here is what I got to after many tries and searches:

```
# Convert the lats and longs you have into the coordinate system
# Convert the non-cartesian lats/lons to a sensible cartesian system.
ssdal = ccrs.Sinusoidal()
coords = ssdal.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), lons, lats)

# Next, handle the invalid values:
data = np.ma.masked_invalid(data)
xs = np.ma.masked_invalid(coords[..., 0])
ys = np.ma.masked_invalid(coords[..., 1])

data.mask = np.logical_or(data.mask, xs.mask, ys.mask)

# Plot data:
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.Sinusoidal())
cmap = plt.get_cmap('terrain')
pc = ax.pcolor(xs, ys, data, cmap=cmap)
cbar = fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax, shrink=0.5, orientation='horizontal')
ax.coastlines()
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
```

This works well for a subset:
[image]

Although I still get:

```
/home/user/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py:2009: UserWarning: The input coordinates to pcolor are interpreted as cell centers, but are not monotonically increasing or decreasing. This may lead to incorrectly calculated cell edges, in which case, please supply explicit cell edges to pcolor.
  result = super().pcolor(*args, **kwargs)
```

But the whole globe, or even a lat=-70,70 and lon=-120,120 rectangle fails, repeating the following message twice:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
/home/capalbof/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/predicates.py:108: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in is_ccw
  return lib.is_ccw(geometry, **kwargs)
Error in callback <function _draw_all_if_interactive at 0x7efcfa15e290> (for post_execute):
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:120 in _draw_all_if_interactive
    draw_all()

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py:132 in draw_all
    manager.canvas.draw_idle()

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2082 in draw_idle
    self.draw(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:400 in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:95 in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:3175 in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py:131 in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py:535 in draw
    return super().draw(renderer=renderer, **kwargs)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:3064 in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py:131 in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py:972 in draw
    super().draw(renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py:351 in draw
    transform, offset_trf, offsets, paths = self._prepare_points()

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py:328 in _prepare_points
    paths = [transform.transform_path_non_affine(path)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py:328 in <listcomp>
    paths = [transform.transform_path_non_affine(path)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py:2439 in transform_path_non_affine
    return self._a.transform_path_non_affine(path)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py:182 in transform_path_non_affine
    geoms = cpatch.path_to_geos(src_path,

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/patch.py:166 in path_to_geos
    geom = sgeom.Polygon(path_verts[:-1, :])

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py:230 in __new__
    shell = LinearRing(shell)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py:104 in __new__
    geom = shapely.linearrings(coordinates)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/decorators.py:77 in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~/miniconda3/envs/atmocor-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/creation.py:173 in linearrings
    return lib.linearrings(coords, out=out, **kwargs)

GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

I get the problem is:

```
GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

But have no idea how to follow up.

**Note**:
I tried contourf, it works!, but then I get, obviously, discrete colors :/.
I tried pcolormesh, filling the masked values in xs and ys with 0, cuz the function does not take masked or invalid values in x or y. Results ain't good.
It works fine (to the look) using scatter, but this is a trick and not a faithful representation of the raster with its 'pixels'.

Any suggestions?